# Limiting probabilities in Markov Decision Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

Do limiting probabilities exist for discrete-time Markov Decision Process, given that the actions are deterministic? If so, how should it be calculated?
Please provide links to notes/references, if any.